# could not install the upgrades the upgrade has aborted. your system is in an unusable state. a recovery will run now (dpkg -configure -s)

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

No matter what I try to fix this, I usually get this error messages:

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/stuts' near line 24995 package 'liblz4-1':
package has field 'Multi-Arch: same' but is missing architecture
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
```

I've tried to run `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a` but `-a` is not found in ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You probably meant to do `dpkg --configure -a`. If you do `dpkg-reconfigure -a` the system will look for a package called `-a`.

Comment: From what I was reading, dpkg --configure -a only configures packages that have yet to be configured, but it doesn't reconfigure broken packages on dpkg.

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh liblz4-1`?

Comment: I get the same error as above :(

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/), I decided to use nano and delete the whole block. Then I ran `dpkg --configure -a`, and this fixed my broken package.